# How can I validate using XSD that two XML attributes have different values?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

Let's say I have following XML:

```
<root>
    <element source="source1" target="target1" />
    <element source="source2" target="target2" />
<root>
```

Is it possible to write an XSD, which would check whether source and target of each element are different? Two different elements can specify the same source or the same targets but the source and target of a particular element must not be the same.

I need to use XSD 1.0 so I can't use asserts.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `xs:unique` for this, both in XSD 1.0 and XSD 1.1. Something like:

```
<xs:unique name="uniqueSourceAndTarget">
    <xs:selector xpath="tns:element"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@source"/>
    <xs:field xpath="@target"/>
</xs:unique>
```

Untested.